# How to find the factors of a number?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, factors

You are given a non-negative integer n. Find the number of divisors of this number from the range [2, n-1].
input: An integer non-negative number n not exceeding 1000.
output: Integer non-negative number

I tried the code a bit, but I can't always get the correct result.

```
%include"io.inc"
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    ;write your code here
    GET_UDEC 4, eax
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, 0
 cycle:
    cmp eax, ebx
    jbe end;
    xor edx, edx
    div ebx
    mul eax, ebx
    inc ebx
    cmp edx, 0
    jne cycle;
    inc ecx;
    jmp cycle;
 end:
    PRINT_UDEC 4, ecx
    NEWLINE
    
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Please point it out for me.

Comment: It is not clear what your algorithm is. Please add comments to explain what your code is doing.

Comment: @RaymondChen；I am trying to divide every number in [2,n-1] by the input number n, when the remainder is 0, that number is a factor of the number n. Whenever the remainder is 0, add 1 to the counter, and finally output the value of the counter.

Comment: @RaymondChen；GET_UDEC 4, eax;input n
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, 0;counter
 cycle:
    cmp eax, ebx;
    jbe end;When ebx exceeds n-1, stop the loop.
    xor edx, edx
    div ebx; mod
    mul eax, ebx;After each div, the value of eax will change. 
                ;I don't know how to keep it as the number n entered at the beginning.
    inc ebx;By adding 1 to ebx, each number in [2,n-1] is reached.
    cmp edx, 0
    jne cycle;when edx!=0, continue to cycle
    inc ecx;when edx=0,counter = counter + 1
    jmp cycle;

Comment: Please add the explanation to the question. The comment "I don't know how to keep it as the number n entered at the beginning." appears to be the root of the problem, since you are able to explain everything in the program except that part.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I can't always get the correct result.

The reason is that, with each iteration of the loop, you change the dividend, while the dividend is supposed to remain constant. I see that you have added a `mul eax, ebx` instruction in an attempt to restore the dividend to its original value, but sadly that instruction alone does not recreate the dividend in case there was a remainder from the division. What would have worked is `imul eax, ebx` followed by `add eax, edx` (1), but the preferred solution would be to reload the dividend before each division. Either use `push eax` and `pop eax` (2), or load EAX from a spare register that was initialized with the inputted number (3).

- Solution 1

  ```
     GET_UDEC 4, eax
     mov  ebx, 2
     mov  ecx, 0
    cycle:
     cmp  eax, ebx
     jbe  end
     xor  edx, edx
     div  ebx
     IMUL EAX, EBX    <<<< Does not destroy the remainder in EDX
     ADD  EAX, EDX    <<<<
     inc  ebx
     cmp  edx, 0
     jne  cycle
     inc  ecx
     jmp  cycle
    end:
  ```
- Solution 2

  ```
     GET_UDEC 4, eax
     mov  ebx, 2
     mov  ecx, 0
    cycle:
     cmp  eax, ebx
     jbe  end
     xor  edx, edx
     PUSH EAX         <<<<
     div  ebx
     POP  EAX         <<<<
     inc  ebx
     cmp  edx, 0
     jne  cycle
     inc  ecx
     jmp  cycle
    end:
  ```
- Solution 3

  ```
     GET_UDEC 4, eax
     MOV  ESI, EAX    <<<<
     mov  ebx, 2
     mov  ecx, 0
    cycle:
     cmp  eax, ebx
     jbe  end
     xor  edx, edx
     div  ebx
     MOV  EAX, ESI    <<<<
     inc  ebx
     cmp  edx, 0
     jne  cycle
     inc  ecx
     jmp  cycle
    end:
  ```

### You can stop the loop much earlier

> Input is a non-negative number N not exceeding 1000.
> Find the number of divisors of this number from the range [2, N-1].

Consider N=1000. Your present code will divide 1000 by every number in the range [2,999]. That's a total of 998 divisions! Now look what happens once you start dividing 1000 by numbers in the range [501,999]: the remainder will never be zero and so the code will never again have to increment ECX. Short story, you can stop the loop at EBX above N/2.

```
     GET_UDEC 4, eax
     MOV  EDI, EAX    <<<<
     SHR  EDI, 1      <<<< EDI is now N/2
     MOV  ESI, EAX    <<<<
     XOR  ECX, ECX    <<<<
     mov  ebx, 2
    cycle:
     CMP  EBX, EDI    <<<< Exits on EBX > N/2, and also exits on N < 4
     JA   end         <<<<
     xor  edx, edx
     div  ebx
     MOV  EAX, ESI    <<<<
     inc  ebx
     TEST EDX, EDX    <<<<
     JNZ  cycle       <<<<
     inc  ecx
     jmp  cycle
    end:
```

Comment: What assembler accepts `mul eax, ebx` as `mul ebx`?  Given the tags, I was worried that NASM did, but no, it correctly rejects it.  That sounds like a recipe for disaster, exactly like here.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wonder, if NASM rejects `mul eax, ebx`, how did the OP manage to assemble and run the code saying that results were off. I will rework that paragraph in my answer.

Comment: There are of course even more efficient algorithms, only finding the *prime* factors, so e.g. 1000 breaks into `2*2*2*5*5*5`, so you'd stop after a few iterations.  (The last division by 5 gives `1` with no remainder so you have all the factors).  But then you have to find all unique combinations of the prime factors to get the list of all divisors.  It's still much more efficient than many trial divisions for many inputs, but would take more code and more work to even get the algorithm right.  And would need some temporary storage for a dictionary of prime factors using some data structure.

Comment: Yeah, IDK how they assembled it, unless there was a bug / misfeature in some older version of NASM.  Or this isn't a [mcve] and they edited some version that did assemble into this version that doesn't; I think that's more likely.  Or some braindead macro package if it's possible to define a 2-operand macro that internally uses the 1-operand instruction?

Comment: @SepRoland Thanks for your answer, I solved my problem now. Sorry for not paying attention to this topic recently, because I am studying the content of the next chapter. I now have a new problem.

Comment: @SepRoland Can you tell me how to use the way you showed in the comments: mul eax, ebx;?

Comment: @jie The instruction `mul eax, ebx` is not valid! You can write `imul eax, ebx` (as in my answer's solution 1: `imul eax, ebx` `add eax, edx`) or else write `mul ebx` as in: `push edx` `mul ebx` `pop edx` `add eax, edx`.